# Nimbus Sans L rendering TM in superscript in Firefox only... browser bug?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem where the project I'm working on renders the letters TM together always in superscript only in Firefox.  Here is a jsfiddle that lets you see the problem in action: https://jsfiddle.net/2aLp0zbc/1/

I don't know if this is a browser bug or a corrupted font file (works fine in all the other browsers I've tested) or if I'm missing something else. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NimbusSansL';

    src: url('https://dl.dropbox.com/s/8u7missp60h2c32/nimbus-sans-l_regular-webfont.woff2?dl=1') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}

body {
    font-family: 'NimbusSansL';
}
```

Comment: I just tried using `text-transform` as a work around and *it still puts it in superscript*. That's just *weird*.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not putting it in superscript, it's replacing TM with the ™ character. Very strange but most likely something wrong with the ligatures in the font.

Comment: @joshhunt but you can still select the letters separately and the ­™ ligature is a single character.  I'm leaning toward my having a version of the font that is broken in some way that only Firefox renders wrong.

Comment: The reason you can select the characters separately is because they are still considered separate characters even though they use a different glyph. For example if you have "ff" it will still register it as "ff" but it might use a different glyph to display it rather than two "f" glyphs. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also see my answer for a possible fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's not putting it in superscript, it's replacing TM with the ™ character. Very strange but most likely something wrong with the [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) in the font.

To fix it you can add this to your css:

```
font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures;
```

Note that this might effect other ligatures in the font.

Comment: I was also alerted to this setting which I went with:

font-feature-settings: "liga" off;

Comment: I tried that also and it didn't seem to work for me. Turns out I just had the syntax wrong, you are right that works also.

Comment: Though as far as I can tell they do exactly the same thing? Don't know too much about these settings.

Comment: I had the same problem and `font-variant-ligatures: no-contextual;` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something going on with your font file. when i change the font to Arial, the TM goes back to normal.

https://jsfiddle.net/2aLp0zbc/7/

```
body {
    font-family: arial, 'NimbusSansL';
}
```